# Eloquent JS: Chessboard – why is first row misaligned?

Tags: javascript

```
function chessBoard (size) {
    result = "";
    for (var s = 1; s <= size; s++ ){
        for (var c = 1; c <= size; c++){
            if ((s + c) % 2 == 0) {
                result = result + " ";
            }
            else {
                result = result + "#";
            }   
        }
        result = result + "\n";
    }
    console.log(result);
}
 chessBoard(8);
```

Result:

```
  # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Why is the first line of the "chessboard" result misaligned in this code? Help me understand what needs to be changed. It should look like:

```
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Comment: looks like second version here http://jsfiddle.net/ah92wLmp/ Same as if I run it in console also ( in FF)

Comment: @charlietfl strange because I get the first version on chrome. I'm unsure why. Assumed it was a code issue?

Comment: I'm using Chrome and I get the correct result.

Comment: perhaps it's a console issue?

Comment: Yes, it's the console. Try `console.log("abc\ndef")`, you'll see that the first line is indented.

Comment: @Barmar that just puts more space in the first line.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. In Chrome, `console.log()` puts a space before the string it's logging.

Comment: @Barmar alas it is! should've tested that first. I was going through the code thinking I was going crazy for the longest time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @barmar: Chrome automatically puts a space before the string it's logging